# C++ - Changes wrong copy of object

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
//MAIN FILE ----------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "price_info.h"
#include "producer.h"

using namespace std;


void printName(string MyName){
    cout << MyName << endl;
}

int main(){
    PriceInfo* instance = new PriceInfo(5.0);
    Producer* ProducerInstance = new Producer();

    thread consumer1{*instance, "Consumer 1"};
    thread consumer2{*instance, "Consumer 2"};
    thread consumer3{*instance, "Consumer 3"};
    thread producer{*ProducerInstance, ref(*instance)};

    consumer1.join();
    consumer2.join();
    consumer3.join();
    producer.join();
}



//PriceInfo - File ------------------------------------------
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

mutex mu;

class PriceInfo{
private:
    double price;
public:
    PriceInfo(double price_){
        set(price_);
    }
    void operator()(string givenName){
        while (true){
            std::chrono::milliseconds sleeptime(250);
            this_thread::sleep_for(sleeptime);
            mu.lock();
            cout << givenName << ": " << get() << endl;
            mu.unlock();
        }
    }
    double get(){
        return this->price;
    }
    void set(double givenPrice){
        std::chrono::milliseconds sleeptime(500);
        this_thread::sleep_for(sleeptime);
        if (givenPrice > 0){
            this->price = givenPrice;
        } else {
            this->price = 0;
        }
    }
};



//Producer-File --------------------------------------------
#pragma once
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include "price_info.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>

class Producer{
private:

    public:
        Producer();
            void operator()(PriceInfo);
        };
    Producer::Producer(){
}

void Producer::operator()(PriceInfo priceInfo_){
    while(true){
        sleep(1);

        random_device rd;
        mt19937 gen{rd()};
        uniform_int_distribution<> dis{0, 7000};

        double changePrice = (dis(gen)-2000)/1000.0;
        priceInfo_.set(2);
        cout << "set2" << endl;
        cout << priceInfo_.get() << endl;
    }
}
```

I've got this code - this is the simplified version of our problem. In this case, the consumer-threads should "cout" their "price"-Variable using the get()-Funktion. The producer-Thread should change the price to a random value between 0 and 5. There is a little sleeptime in nearly every function but this does not have much effect.

The Problem now is, that the "SET"-Funtion does not really change the value of the variable "price". So get() still returns the value "5", which was set in the constructor in "MAIN-FILE". Here is the output.

```
Consumer 3: 5
Consumer 2: 5
Consumer 1: 5
Consumer 2: 5
Consumer 1: 5
Consumer 3: 5
Consumer 1: 5
Consumer 2: 5
Consumer 3: 5
Consumer 2: 5
Consumer 1: 5
Consumer 3: 5
Consumer 1: 5
Consumer 2: 5
Consumer 3: 5
```

I don't really get the problem there. Have I messed up with those pointers/references?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You don't serialize the access to `price`. Anything can be printed, really.

Comment: Probably not related to the actual problem, but your code has a blatant memory leak - do you even need to allocate objects with `new`?

Comment: `Producer::operator()` only modifies its parameter, which is a copy of `*instance`. I would recommend that you study more C++ fundamentals before embarking on multithreading.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know, that's what we actually want to achieve... Pretty long story, but the program should mess around with these unlocked sections in multiple threads :)

Comment: I'm guessing you came from Java, right? As moldnbilo said, you're passing `PriceInfo priceInfo_` by _value_, not by _reference_. In C++, you must explicitly make a parameter by-reference (even if the type is a class). Besides that, you're not using the mutex inside the `Producer` function.